# Get polygon object on polygon click angular 2 google maps

Tags: angular, angular2-google-maps

I am using https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/index/SebmGoogleMapPolygon-directive.html , for google map ,

```js
  
      
       <sebm-map-polygon *ngFor="let polygon of polygonPathDatas" 
        [paths]="polygon.path"
        [clickable] = "true"
        strokeColor ="#00000"
        [strokeWeight]=".6"      
        [editable]="false"
        [draggable]="false" 
        (polyClick)="click($event)" 
        (polyDblClick)="delete($event)">
      </sebm-map-polygon>
```

how can i get polygon object from click

```js
  click($event: any) {
    console.log(event);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the instance of the array in the event handler.

(polyClick)="click($event)" becomes  (polyClick)="click(polygon)"